# Skip all items after first one with same id

Tags: c#, linq, select, collections

Assume i have `List<CustomObject> list`.

`CustomObject` has next structure :

```
public class CustomObject
{
  public int coId{get;set;}
  public List<SubCustObj> subList{get;set;}
  public DateTime datePublish{get;set;}
}
public class SubCustObj
{
  public int Id{get;set;}
  public Region rRegion{get;set;} 
}
// Region : for you it's only important to know that it has regionId
```

If in List exists `CustomObject`'s with same `coId` in `Region` i need to leave only 1 element with most recent `datePublish`. In other words, for one `coId` - one `Region`. How can i do it?

```
//list it's List<CustomObject>
    var toDelete = ist.SelectMany(r =>
                                       r.subList.Where(m => r.subList.Count() > 2)
                                        .Select(rm => rm.rRegion.regionID));
```

this code select ids of region which are repeated, but what todo next i don't know.

---

Some new idea : Can  i group elements by regionId and after it select only first element in that group?

Comment: You seem to understand linq fairly, well, trying putting in Distinct(), Looks like it might go at the end of your select.

Comment: @CalvinSmith, but this will just select unique regions while it can be more that 1 region to delete with same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select pairs `(Region, CustomObject)`, order by `datePublish`, group by region, and pick the first item from each group:

```
var res = list
    .SelectMany(c => c.subList.Select(s => new {Custom = c, Region = s.rRegion}))
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Custom.datePublish)
    .GroupBy(p => p.regionId)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

This gives you pairs of `CustomObject`, `Region` such that regions are not repeated (`CustomObject`s may be repeated, though).

Comment: thanks, this make sense. Please give me some time to test it. If it's ok, i will accept your answer, in other case i let you know if something is wrong. Thanks again

Comment: yes, i think it works, but i also need to add `Distinct()` to get unique `CustomObject`